# Using SessionHandlerInterface with MySQL database ...please advise

Tags: php, security

I have made the following code by following http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

AND

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Here I am using MySQL database to store and retrieve session variables. This code works fine. However it would be great if you are kind enough to point out the mistakes and share your input about this code.

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    { 

   $host = 'localhost';
   $user = '******';
   $pass = '******';
   $name = '*******';
   $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
   $this->db = $mysqli;
   return true;

    }

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        if(!isset($this->read_stmt)) {
      $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
   }
   $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
   $this->read_stmt->execute();
   $this->read_stmt->store_result();
   $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
   $this->read_stmt->fetch();
   $key = $this->getkey($id);
   $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
   return $data;
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
         // Get unique key
   $key = $this->getkey($id);
   // Encrypt the data
   $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);

   $time = time();
   if(!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
      $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
   }

   $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
   $this->w_stmt->execute();
   return true;
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
       if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
      $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");
   }
   $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
   $this->delete_stmt->execute();
   return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {
      $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE set_time < ?");
   }
   $old = time() - $max;
   $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
   $this->gc_stmt->execute();
   return true;
    }

   private function getkey($id) {
   if(!isset($this->key_stmt)) {
      $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
   }
   $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
   $this->key_stmt->execute();
   $this->key_stmt->store_result();
   if($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) { 
      $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);
      $this->key_stmt->fetch();
      return $key;
   } else {
      $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
      return $random_key;
   }

}
   private function encrypt($data, $key) {
   $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
   $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
   return $encrypted;
   }
    private function decrypt($data, $key) {
   $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
   $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return $decrypted;
   }
}

$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

Thanks for your time

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You are not locking the session. That's the biggest mistake.

Whenever a request in PHP starts a session and the data is read from file, PHP acquires a lock on that file, and any parallel requests will stop and wait on the `session_start()` function until the lock has been release.

If you do not lock, the following will happen: The first request reads all data from the database. The second requests also reads the same data. The first request changes a value to A. The second request changes another value to B. The first request ends and writes back it's A to the database. Then the second request writes back the changes with it's B, but without A. DATA IS LOST!

Another thing I noticed: Why do you encode the encrypted data with base64? This is not necessary, databases can accept binary data. The only benefit from this is that your hoster can sell you a bigger machine.

Comment: Thanks Sven .....Great Input. I did not know about locking in php. I'll update the code.